# How to secure Python source code?

Tags: python, iot

Is there any way to protect or hide the source code (python code) from the end users, which is in sd card partition in Linux (OpenWrt) SBC of IOT product ? I have Mediatek Linkit duo Module which contains OpenWrt. Please help.
Solutions I am already familiar with:
1.Byte code
2.Source obfuscation
3.Change properties
4.Change python source code into c or c++ using cython

Comment: What “level” of protection do you need, i.e., how difficult does it need to be access a usable version of the source?

Comment: I just dont want to show my source code to the end user i.e. customer . It should not be readable or understandable at first glance.